# Stringify CMake preprocessor token

Tags: c, string, cmake, c-preprocessor, token

I'm using CMake to compile this example program:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0.0)
set(PROJECT_NAME Main)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

add_definitions(-DSTRING=“test”)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.c)
```

**main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts(STRING);
}
```

---

Compiling gives me the following error:

> ```
> error: expected expression
>     puts(STRING);
>          ^
> <command line>:1:16: note: expanded from here
> #define STRING "test"
> ```

How can I stringify this preprocessor token *without modifying* `main.c`?

Comment: I hope you aren't actually using "smart quotes" in CMakeLists.txt, although your example shows them: `-DSTRING=“test”`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the characters `“` and `”` that are not valid in C:

```
error: expected expression
        puts(STRING);
         ^
<command line>:1:16: note: expanded from here
#define STRING “test”
           ^
1 error generated.
```

You must change `“` and `”` for `"` in your CMakeLists.txt and your program will compile.

Comment: Those quotes I used are what my Mac types out, how do you suggest changing them to your quote style?

Comment: An option just is copy and paste this `"`.

Comment: @syb0rg probably depends on your editor, looks like it's a common feature... https://www.macissues.com/2014/11/03/how-to-disable-smart-quotes-in-os-x/

Comment: Maybe can be the configuration of your keyboard: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120486/quotes-problem-in-mavericks-or-textedit

Comment: That's not a "workaround".  The problem is with your keyboard or whatever application you're using for editing, not with Cmake.